# Search on server database vs local database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I recently started developing for android, and i read about SQLite.

It sounds like it is much faster to search on the device itself, instead on the server, since you save the time of the connections and transfers. is it really so?
or should i keep doing my searches on the server?

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible to keep it local then you should keep it local.

People with slow or no internet connections could have some troubles using your app.

If your local database needs data then you can set up a service which downloads data from the server in the background without the user noticing anything.

Comment: And if my database is really big, wouldn't that make my app really heavy?

Comment: No. It may cost some space (if your database is really that big) but if you query well and put indices on the right columns and other optimizations then you should have no troubles.