# Why, when and how is the best way to use the database in Android applications?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, orm

After almost 2 years of commercial Android development I'm still confused whether use an internal database or not. The documentation of the framework as vague and leaves it up to the developer to decide.

For a specific example: a catalog application that consumes an external API for it's actions, such as getting and updating items. The application stays "locked" when the connection to the Internet is lost, but you can still see the data that was already loaded, such as lists and user profiles. No commenting or data input is accepted.

Balancing between code complexity, user experience and application performance, should I store it in the database and ensure its consistency using an ORM, or the database is too expensive and I should only store the data while the app is opened?

Thinking about the experience, it makes sense to store in the database, because after a restart I'll be able to preload the data, event without internet. For older devices, it seems logic to store in disk or database because memory is more limited.

How do you guys decide whether to use it or not in your android projects?

Comment: Possible DUPLICATE : see [Search on server database vs local database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22289100/6874831) and [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/251685/should-data-be-stored-to-local-database-in-android-when-heavily-using-rest-servi)

Comment: @P.Bra The first link you supplied doesn't answer my question in depth. The second one is really interesting, but the main goal of the question is not the same. For the example it was supplied, it should not use the database, but my question here is generic: "How do you guys decide whether to use it or not in your android projects?". 

I want to know for any kind of project, what are the main aspects I should look to consider using a database. What kind of key features requires a database conceptually?

Answer (score 0):

I think FireBase Database solves pretty much all these issues. Take a look at it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).